# Is there an abstract jQuery tracking plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, google-analytics

Is there any jQuery plugin that abstracts tracking actions (clicks, ajax loads, etc) from other libraries like Google Analytics, Omniture, etc.? Such a plugin would make switching from Google Analytics to e.g. Omniture much easier.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.

There is a [plugin for google analytics](http://aktagon.com/projects/jquery/google-analytics/), and a [plugin for omniture](https://github.com/jbueza/jquery-omniture), but not one that can do either.  Perhaps you could normalize the methods of these plugins yourself?